# Keycloak OIDC and AWS ALBs

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, amazon-elb, aws-alb

Is there a way to get Keycloak to work as an OIDC Provider for AWS ALBs?

I have tried and tried and I am just getting stuck with 500 Internal Server.

I created a new confidential client and provided the ALB with the clientID and secret as well as the OIDC Urls. I read a few years back about an issue with Bearer vs bearer in the headers, but I couldn't validate that this was the issue, or that it is still an issue with ALBs.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is my configuration. I have adjusted the URLs to be generic.

```
AWS -
Issuer: https://login.example.com/auth/realms/example
Auth Endpoint: https://login.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/auth
Token Endpoint: https://login.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token
User info Endpoint: https://login.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
Client ID: ExampleApp
Client secret: supersecret
```

[aws_oidc_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upnuA.png)

```
Keycloak -
Client ID: ExampleApp
Root URL: https://li.stagingweb.example.com
Valid Redirect URIs: https://li.stagingweb.example.com/*
Admin URL: https://li.stagingweb.example.com
Web Origins: https://li.stagingweb.example.com/*
```

[keycloak_client_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNfQl.png)
[keycloak_cred_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adaX0.png)

The response I get back from this configuration is just a 500 error. The Load Balancer logs report:

```
5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 -"li.stagingweb.example.com" -1 2020-04-27T18:11:34.497000Z "authenticate" "-" "AuthTokenEpRequestFailed" "-" "-"
```

This is the request that gets the 500 error:

```
https://li.stagingweb.example.com/oauth2/idpresponse?state=PWISnbHmRCVpxmqyn%2FrKsHdJzbKFnfz5GxhnlCyVdnxRVV%2F9kvj7O0JCjQOuf1DNL08h821PorJGGa3%2F4fzFymulG8sS%2FxhLFQS5gNrpuQyCf9DCzrwFxkIbG3I2sHywK7%2FeDmfYUH6Rej%2FEJ4RQwdjpjm76Z1wycw%2FGjQIRxehaTqNtCS%2FdXhm2oag%2FBnY%2FkuMiB8Q%3D&session_state=3a94a1d6-5e75-491b-a231-e4a1a469e5cb&code=23364bac-92e9-4094-9dc3-19c15eb42e7c.3a94a1d6-5e75-491b-a231-e4a1a469e5cb.9723ee49-5bca-4ff6-8a13-f7539b0bc28c
```

Hopefully I didn't post any info I shouldn't have :)

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but you didn't provide your configuration and detail what generated that error 500, so it is hard to say what is a problem in your case.

Comment: I added my config and some more detail to the post.

Comment: `AuthTokenEpRequestFailed` = `There is an error response (non-2XX) from the token endpoint.` Check Keycloak logs or contact AWS support what was the actual response from the token endpoint.

Comment: @con_rad were you able to solve this? I am thinking it might be due to inbound/outbound rules in security group and route table configurations in your network subnets. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-500-issues

detailed article: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-configure-authentication-alb

Answer (score 0):

AWS ALB expected whatever the endpoints configured inside aws ALB are accessible via public internet. Else, it would end up with internal server error. SO have a public site and get it configured.